# Code executes differently depending if I use the pickled object or not

Tags: python, pickle

I'm using the pickle (Cpickle) function in python for the first time, with limited success.

If I pickle and object something and then re-load it from the pickle file, I'm assuming that it should be identical to the original object, right?

However, when the code runs for the first time, I create a list of classes **t** and then pickle:

```
with open(pklfilename, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(t, f)
```

And the code runs fine the whole way through.

When I run the code any subsequent time:

```
if os.path.exists(pklfilename):
    with open(pklfilename, "rb") as f:
        t = pickle.load(f)
```

The pickle seems to work and load okay, but in this case the code fails later:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I can't escape the idea someone the list is not the same once it has been pickled and dumped back out - but surely that's the point of pickling.

I realize I haven't provided the code, which I don't think will help as I am using packages that have been written by other people at my university and so the objects that I am picking are not types that would be recognizable, `t[0] = <class blah.blah.blah>`.

Comment: You should provide what ``t`` is.

Comment: I thought I did. type(t[0]), type(t[1]) etc.. returns <class blah.blah.blah> (the blahs won't mean anything to anyone). t is just the list of them.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import pickle

t = [1, 2, 3]
with open('abc', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(t, f)

with open('abc', "rb") as f:
    x = pickle.load(f)

print(x)
```